# Heroku Docker image deploy

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-image

I am trying to deploy docker image to Heroku but got error: unsupported: Your Docker image must specify a `CMD` instruction.
How to fix that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code below the line started with `RUN`:

```
CMD ["--debug=5"]
```

It will solve your current problem, no guarantee for further problems :)